# update data from form in iframe simultaneously

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I have a php file**(index.php)** with a form. And I have another php file**(template1.php)** with showing data, it shows data after filled form from index.php after submit.
Now, template1.php should be show in index.php and if I type in input field of index.php form then, field data should be show in template1.php simultaneously.
For this I am using iframe. But no solution find.

**index.php is:**

```
<iframe src="templates/alltemplates/template1.php" height="200" width="300" id="myframe"></iframe> 

<form id="submit_form" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-md-6 mb-50">
    <span class="input">
     <label class="" for="cf-email" style="font-weight: 500;">Upload Logo </label>
      <input class="input__field cf-validate" type="file" id="logo" name="logo" accept="image/png,image/jpeg" />
    </span>
  </div>

 <div class="col-md-6 mb-50">
  <span class="input">
   <label class="" for="cf-email" style="font-weight: 500;">Business Speciality </label>
    <input class="input__field cf-validate" type="text" id="business_title" name="business_title" maxlength="40" oninput="iframetype('business_title', business_title.value)" />
  </span>                                                
 </div>
```

**js file is:**

```
function iframetype(id, value) 
{ 
 var iframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
 var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById(id);
 var iframeid = $(elmnt).attr('id');
}
```

in js, I got the id of iframe  tag, but in index.php and template1.php ids are same. So no need to find the id from template.php
I need, when I type in ** Business Speciality field** in index.php, then in  tag with id **business_title** in template1.php should be change. And same as image upload.
I tried yeasterday all day. But did't get any solution. Please give me solution.

**template1.php is:**

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 backgroundf0f0f0 center170">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="logo col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 offset-sm-3 offset-md-2">
    <img src="../../uploads/logo/file.jpg from index.php" alt="Logo" width="100%" height="auto" />
  </div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 businessheadlineblack pdt10">
 <h3 id="business_title">data from index.php</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would be looking for is the `window.postMessage()` method.

> **window.postMessage()**
>
> The window.postMessage() method safely enables cross-origin communication between Window objects; e.g., between a page and a pop-up that it spawned, or between a page and an iframe embedded within it.

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

---

So basically, you can use the `onkeyup()` function on your input element to capture key events. Within the `onkeyup()` call the messaging function and pass it the current value of the input element.

```
<input class="input__field cf-validate" type="text" id="business_title" name="business_title" maxlength="40" onkeyup="sendMessage(this.value);" />
```

The messaging function will then send the value to the iframe (the script below is part of the main page)

```
function sendMessage(value) {
    // get the iframe's content window
    var contentWindow = document.getElementById('iframeID').contentWindow;
    contentWindow.postMessage(value, "http://www.example.com");  // <-- your website URL
}
```

And on the receiving side, the iframe will simply update the targeted input value with the received value (the script below is inside the iframe):

```
function receiveMessage(event)
{
    // Do we trust the sender of this message?
    if (event.origin !== "http://example.com:8080") // <-- your URL
    return;

    document.getElementById("business_title").innerHTML= event.data;
}

window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

Comment: it is my local host..So path of localhost...means http://localhost/arknewtech/files/template1.php

Comment: If one is embedded in the other then both are on the same URL. You type instead of the URL whatever you see in the browser in the address bar.

Comment: In sendMessage()-> website url is  localhost/arknewtech/files/template1.php

Comment: Do a console.log(event.origin); inside your receiveMessage function, and above the if(event.origin ...), and use what it gives you

Comment: window.addEventListener('message',function(){
            document.getElementById("business_title").innerHTML= event.data;

            });

Comment: But how I can also send id and related that id data will be show in template1.php

Comment: You can send the data in JSON format like this: `var msg = JSON.stringify( {'id': 'someID', 'imageSRC': 'someImageSRC'} );` and then simply send the `msg` variable inside the `postMessage` method. On the receiving side use `var data = JSON.parse(event.data);`. And then you can access it's properties by using `data.someID` or `data.someImageSRC`, etc.